# How to load objects using multiple RKObjectManagers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, restkit

I was using https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Using-Multiple-Base-URLs-%28and-Multiple-Object-Managers%29 as a guide.

I know it's possible to create multiple Object Managers and retain them in the appdelegate.  What I dont understand is how do I load objects from that specific object manager with the desired baseURL in a different view controller late on if only the first of the object managers is a shared singleton.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found out that using the baseURL in the path when loading objects will help distinguish the two object managers.